# To find the area of the region outside $r = 3 + 4 \sin(θ)$ and inside $r = 5 + 2 \sin(θ)$ from $0 \leq θ \leq π/2$

Tags: calculus, area, education

The answer I got is wrong. I started by finding the derivative and then substituting my values for theta, not sure if that is right.

Comment: I do not understand why you are finding derivative. The radii of both curves are given. You just need to find area between the two curves using the limits of radius and of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the graph between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. You need to simply consider the lower limit and upper limit of the radius between two curves.

[image]

The integral is simply

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{3+4\sin\theta}^{5+2\sin\theta} r \ dr \ d\theta$